# Laravel - Erase all cache / redis keys that contain a specific string

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

Is it possible to erase all keys in redis using Laravel that match a specific string? For instance, if I wanted to forget keys that have the word products, it would forget the following keys:

laravel:896235872385237588327582370375acaca235325:products-list
laravel:896235872385237588327582370375acaca235325:products-categories

I would run this on the redis server but I'm wondering if there's anything better that could be run via Laravel directly:

`redis-cli keys "*" | grep "products" | xargs redis-cli DEL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not:

```
public function forget($key_name)
{
    $redis = Cache::getRedis();
    $keys = $redis->keys("*$key_name*");
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $redis->del($key);
        $count++;
    }      
    return $count;  
}
```

And for production environment  SCAN cursor [MATCH pattern] [COUNT count] should be used instead of "keys"

http://redis.io/commands/scan

Because you don't want to run out of memory in case you have tens of thousands keys in redis, and you don't want to block your whole redis instance by using "keys".

Comment: I don't see how this is different conceptually?

Comment: Your solution: get all keys from redis to PHP (may be hundred of thousands) and then filter, my solution: do filtering on redis side.

Answer (score 4):

This is the alternative by using scan instead of keys. Feel free to transform it to a recursive function if needed.

```
public function forgetWildcard(string $pattern, int $maxCountValue = 1000)
{
        $redis = Cache::getRedis();
        $currentCursor = '0';
        do {
            $response = $redis->scan($currentCursor, 'MATCH', $pattern, 'COUNT', $maxCountValue);
            $currentCursor = $response[0];
            $keys = $response[1];
            if (count($keys) > 0) {
                // remove all found keys
                $redis->del($keys);
            }
        } while ($currentCursor !== '0'); // finish if current Cursor is reaching '0'
}
```

*Hint: to make it work for Laravel with prefixes I had to replace the pattern with the following:* `$this->getPrefix().'*:'.$pattern`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do it -- not something you want to do too often because it uses the redis keys command:

```
public function forget($key_name)
    {
        $redis = Cache::getRedis();
        $keys = $redis->keys("*");
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (strpos($key, $key_name)) {
                $redis->del($key);
                $count++;
            }
        }      
        return $count;  
    }
```

Comment: No. Don't do this. Use `SCAN` instead of keys.