# How to delete Redis keys stored in a given Redis set?

Tags: redis

I want to delete Redis keys (and their data set) based on retreiving those keys from a specified set, for example:

```
HMSET id:1 password 123 category milk
HMSET id:2 password 456 category milk
HMSET id:3 password 789 category honey
SADD categories:milk 1 2
SADD categories:honey 3
```

Now I want to delete all the keys belongs to categories:milk (In that case: id:1 & id:2).
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141982/4299353)  details the solution. 
Basically, you have to retrieve the KEYS based on a pattern, looping through the results, and then using DEL to remove each one.

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering if it is posible to make those operations with one Redis command.