# Remove all items from cache whose key start with string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-events, laravel-cache

I want to remove all the cache items whose key is starting with custom string.

Currently, I have a `PermissionObserver` for the `Permission` model with a custom trait `ObserverEvent` to called this `handle` method.

```
class PermissionObserver
{
    use ObserverEvent;

    private function handle(Permission $permission)
    {
        $emails = User::pluck('email');
        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $key  = 'permission_index_'. $email;
           if (cache()->has($key)) {
                cache()->forget($key);
           }
        }

        $ids = User::pluck('id');
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $key1  = 'permission_create_users_'. $id;
            $key2  = 'permission_edit__users_'. $id;
            if (cache()->has($key1)) {
                 cache()->forget($key1);
            }
            if (cache()->has($key2)) {
                cache()->forget($key2);
            }
        }

        // It will continue like this....

        logger()->build(CUSTOM_BUILD_LOG_CHANNEL)->info("PERMISSION_CACHE_CLEARED");
    }
}
```

Now it's getting bigger and performance issues. Also, I have this type of logic for all models.

**Update**

I am not using any `redis`, `database`, `dynamodb`, `memcached` or `octane` driver for the cache store. I am using default storage i.e. `file` so provide the solution accordingly.

**Is there a way to clear all the cache with starting with string permission so that I can do like this.**

```
cache()->forget('permission*') // this doesn't work
```

Comment: Since you are using a file cache you can remove all the `cache()->has` calls because by default the file cache won't delete an entry unless it exists and will return falls if it doesn't delete it (rather than failing the call) so you might get "some" speed back.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074418/laravel-erase-all-cache-redis-keys-that-contain-a-specific-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Erase all cache / redis keys that contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074418/laravel-erase-all-cache-redis-keys-that-contain-a-specific-string)